# Getting all assets of imagePaths

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, photosframework

I have a list of imagePaths and I want to use it for getting the PHassets. I was thinking of using `fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:options:)`, it turns out it is deprecated. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

AssetURLs are not imagePaths, they are unique URLs to map the deprecated ALAssets to the newer PHAssets, but do not represent a physical file location.

There are no methods to deal with imagePaths in the Photos framework for a good reason. The file locations for photos/videos in the iOS Photo Library are private and sandboxed. You can not access these image paths directly from your application. Only some Photos framework methods use image path internally and can access the files by settings security scopes temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I don't really need the imagePaths. I just need to use the localIdentifier (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject/1622400-localidentifier) and use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624732-fetchassets. Thanks.